# How do I extract Flash content from a PDF file?

Tags: pdf, flash, extract

I have a PDF file that has a flash file embedded.

How can I can extract that SWF from inside the PDF file?

Update:

I am using Windows 7.

Comment: What?!  A pdf can not have flash content embedded.

Answer (score 3):

Found a product that can do it: [PDFTron's PDF CosEdit](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfcosedit/index.html) can extract the resources.
I opened the a PDF with embedded Rich Media videos in CosEdit, then scrolled to the bottom (where the files with the largest Offset values were kept). For me, these were it. I extracted the resources, and they opened as MP4s. You might want to try MP4, SWF, etc. or inspect the resource's headers to help identify its type.

For a programmatic solution, they have other software as well, and they [published this article](https://blog.pdftron.com/2013/09/11/working-with-pdf-richmedia-annotations/) which appears useful.

Comment: What's your affiliation with that product?

Comment: No affiliation with them, just took me forever to find it. Tried to install Origami PDF on Linux to do it, but it was complicated by PVM.

Comment: Just took me forever to find something, so when I found it I thought I would share it.

Comment: Ok, sorry for being a pain; we just get so much astroturfing here. I've meanwhile found your profile picture at LinkedIn too, so I'm quite sure you're NOT working at PDFTron. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This worked great, thank you so much! In my case I found the files by finding streams that had a Subtype "audio/mpeg". I also changed my stream viewer in  "Customize..." to VLC so I could verify that I could open these files and that they were those I was looking for. Then I just had to save them with Save Stream Data to File.

Comment: URLs provided are no longer available.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OS X, you can try [FileJuicer](http://echoone.com/filejuicer/)

If you are using Windows or Linux you can try [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) (specifically the SWFExtract app)

Comment: SWFExtract "Allows to extract Movieclips, Sounds, Images etc. ***from*** SWF files."