# How can I extract an underlying flash file from a word, pdf or powerpoint file?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, flash, microsoft-powerpoint, extract

I have a software that creates a PDF, word or powerpoint file that contains a flash file that I need. However, I cannot seem to extract that flash file. I have tried using [SWFTools](http://www.swftools.org/) as suggested in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/330904/how-do-i-extract-flash-content-from-a-pdf-file) but with no success. The flash file can indeed be extracted using that approach but it does not work properly (in fact it displays nothing but a white screen). Any suggestions?

The background is that I'm using Xcelsius Present which cannot export directly to SWF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word, you can certainly do it with [Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw65a0we%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), powerpoint [should be no different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213568%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

You might need to code somethig i know, but its not that hard, and i'm sure there are code snippets out there you can use

Comment: Thank you Carlos! I will see if I can do it in VB. It looks pretty straight forward. :)